# Can't run makemigrations after moving modules

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I've got a module named: `validators.py` located at `./project/app1/validators.py`.

To use it, I have imported it inside one of my Models:

```
# app1/models.py
from .validators import validate_something
```

After a while, I decide to move this `validators.py` to a separated directory `utils/` (which contains a `__init__.py` file), so I can use it in all my apps without referencing the `app1`.

Now it's located at: `./project/utils/validators.py`.

After moving the module, I changed my import at the beginning of the Model:

```
# app1/models.py
from utils.validators import validate_something
```

Now that I want to create new migrations using `manage.py makemigrations` I'm getting this error:

```
File "project/app1/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 5, in <module>
    import app1.validators
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app1.validators'
```

I can remove all migrations and regenerate them but I guess there should be another way to resolve this dependency issue.

Comment: did you try from project.utils.validators?

Comment: @Jonas The error is not about `utils/validators.py` it about the previous reference to `app1/validators.py` which no longer exists.

Comment: maybe you can try to delete your migration files and re-migrate

Comment: @Jonas Thanks, But I've already mention that in the question.

Comment: this might help https://docs.divio.com/en/latest/how-to/debug-dependency-conflict/ if not i guess u have  to run zero and re do  the migrations

Comment: You can edit 0001_initial.py to replace ```import app1.validators``` with ```import utils.validators```.